# Are nested private classes considered composition?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, composition

**Background**

I am considering a design that includes a public API class containing many nested private classes. I am doing this for the following reasons:

1. Why private nesting? They will have no use to any other classes except for by my public API class.
2. Why classes in the first place? The objects being represented have a significant amount of functionality that they must be their own classes.
3. Why *many* classes? The functionality of each of the nested classes is too different from one another to be derived from a single kind of class.

**Question**

*With all of what's being stated above, would this design practice be considered "composition" in the strictest sense of the word?*

I would say yes, because I am representing a "part-of" system, where the private classes are part-of the public API class and will never exist outside the lifetime of the API class. That being said, for some reason I think there might be something wrong here. I just want to be sure.

Comment: Nested private classes? You mean you have a class within a class within a class,... ? That's not good. I personally would go with creating another assembly with one single public class and the rest set to internal. That way you still get the benefit of organization while keeping the output (API) of the dll very simple.

Comment: @DavidPacker Would that be considered composition?

Comment: @StevieV: The Access Modifier applied to a class doesn't affect its ability to compose, at least not within the same DLL (in the case of `internal`).

Comment: @RobertHarvey So following your example given at the Wikipedia page, internal classes declared as separate assemblies would still be "composing" with the public API assembly... And thus, what David is saying would technically be composition?

Comment: @DavidPacker When you say assembles, do you mean .DLL files? Why not just use multiple files within a single namespace to represent each class?

Comment: @StevieV: Yes, it would be composition.  What are you getting at?  Is there some technical problem that would be solved by you knowing the correct definition of "composition?"  If there is, you should put that in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, the pure definition of composition wouldn't help me solve any technical problems. I know what composition is (to some degree). I *am* trying to decide if composition is the correct thing for me (entirely separate issue I don't want to combine with this question). In asking *this* question, I am trying to clear up a misconception that I had *about* composition.

Comment: The list of useful things you can do with nested classes is very small.  You could eliminate them from your repertoire and never miss them.  See my answer below.

Comment: @DavidPacker I would still like to see what you meant by saying different assemblies, and if you actually meant files/classes.

Comment: Different assemply = different project, different DLL. By marking a class internal (at least it used to be that way, haven't programmed in C# in some time) you can use a component throughout an entire project (an entire assembly), but another project referencing this project will not see the internal components. You can build fairly complicated but clean-coded code structure with internal classes while not having to expose them to the clients (ie. users) of the project itself.

Comment: @DavidPacker Maybe that will just have to be a question for another time. Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, note that nested classes in Java have an additional feature in that an instance of the nested class (automatically) has access to an instance of the outer class.  This is not the case in C#: you would have to create and capture your own reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Nested classes only provide one benefit over inheritance: *they don't use inheritance.*  The other benefits of composition, namely [**polymorphic behavior and code reuse,**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) are absent in nested classes (unless you have an especially large main class, which I would consider a violation of SRP).

That doesn't mean you shouldn't use them.  It just means they don't fulfill the spirit of composition.